# How to use Hensel's Lemma to find the degree of each irreducible factor of $X^4-5$ in $\mathbb{Q}_{139}[x]$?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

How to use Hensel's Lemma to find the degree of each irreducible factor of $X^4-5$ in $\mathbb{Q}_{139}[x]$? where $\mathbb{Q}_{139}$ denotes the complete field of 139-adic numbers.

I factorised it to $(x^2+12)(x^2-12)$ by modulo 139, then no idea what to do next, one thing is I don't if I can factorise further,so I don't know if it's the time to lift by Hensel's Lemma; another thing is about the I don't what $Q_{139}/(139)$ is.

Comment: @peterag I factorised it to $(x^2+12)(x^2-12)$ by modulo 139, then no idea what to do next, one thing is I don't if I can factorise further, another thing is about the I don't what $Q_{139}/(139)$ is

Comment: The only ideals in a field are the zero ideal (0) and the whole field $(1)$. So you probably want ${\mathbb Z_{139}}/139{\mathbb Z_{139}} ={\mathbb Z}/139{\mathbb Z}  $. Now, in the residue field,  $x^2-a$ factors iff $a$ is a square. So is $12$ a square in the residue field? Is $-12$ a square? Hope this helps!

Comment: @peterag thanks, we are considering $Q_{139}$, how can we get down to $Z_{139}$?

Comment: It's a sub-ring (the ring of integers), right? The factorization of $x^4-5$ over $\mathbb Z_{139}$ is 'the same' as over $\mathbb Q_{139}$. You probably should chat with someone face to face about this...

Comment: @peterag I've provided an answer and would be able to help him with his questions as comments here or on the answer I posted. although I want to say I'm not certain what goes on in $\mathbb{Q}_{p}$ ... But I did assume that the roots would've been the same in $\mathbb{Z}_{139}$ (thats the same as $\mathbb{F}_{139}$?).

Comment: @Davehuff - not quite! Here ${\mathbb Z}_p$ is the a subring of ${\mathbb Q}_p$. It has a maximal ideal $p{\mathbb Z}_p$, and ${\mathbb Z}_p/p{\mathbb Z}_p = {\mathbb F}_p$. So the roots / factorization 'live' in different rings. But one can think that H's lemma gives a relationship between the two... See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel%27s_lemma. - On that page, replace $\cal O$ with $\mathbb Z_p$, and $K= {\mathbb Q}_p$

Comment: @Davehuff - I should have said "under certain conditions (which are satisfied here) H gives a relationship..."

Comment: @peterag sorry can you give more explanations about why  The factorization of $x^4−5$ over $Z_{139}$  is 'the same' as over ℚ139?

Comment: See section 2.16 of Jacobson's basic algebra 1, where it's almost explicitly stated as needed here  (monic polys ) - see the last corollary of the section. I looked up "Gauss's lemma" in Lang's algebra, and Theorem V, 6.3 does it too - I'm sure any algebra book which has G's lemma in the index will have the appropriate theorem - basically if $D$ is a UFD, then so is $D[x]$, and irreducible factors  correspond to those over $K[x]$, where $K$ is the quotient field of $D$, up to the 'content' (common factor of the coeffs in $D$)  of the irr. factors. OK?

Comment: Namely, for ex,  $p =3x -3$ is not irreducible over $\mathbb Z[x]$, but only because there is the common factor of $3$, which is not invertible (not a unit) in $\mathbb Z$, although it is in $\mathbb Q$ . So, as irreducible factors are only given up to unit, $p$ is irreducible over the rationals, but not over the integers (the extra $3$ is an irr. factor). On the other hand $q = 2x-3$ is irreducible both over the integers and the rationals, as the gcd of the coeffs is $\pm 1$. OK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know how to use Hensels lemma but here's what I can show you. First we need to factor $X^4-5$;

$(X-\sqrt[4]{5})(X+\sqrt[4]{5})(X-\imath\sqrt[4]{5})(X+\imath\sqrt[4]{5})$.

We can rewrite that as $(X^2-\sqrt{5})(X^2+\sqrt{5})$, but remember the former factoring.

Since $139 \equiv 4 \pmod{5}$, we see that $\sqrt{5}$ 'exists' in $\mathbb{F}_{139}$, we can factor $X^4-5$ as $(X^2-c)(X^2+c)$ for $c^2 \equiv 5 \pmod{139}$, which we can find (and you've already found it).

Assume that there exists an element in $\mathbb{F}_{139}$ that satisfies $b^4 \equiv 5$. That means $5=\omega^{4k}$ for some multiplicative ggenerator $\omega$ of $\mathbb{F}_{139}$. If this element exists, we can only factor $X^4-5$ as

$(X-b)(X+b)(X^2+c)$

since $139 \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$ and that implies no element satisfies $X^2=-1$ here.

Now Assume that there doesn't exist an element $b^4 \equiv 5$. This means $5=\omega^{2(2k+1)}$. If we take $c$ though, it's of the form

$\omega^{2k+1}$, which means

$-c=\omega^{\frac{139-1}{2}} \cdot \omega^{2k+1}=\omega^{2k+70}=\omega^{2(k+35)}=d^{2}$

and so $X^2=-c$ must have a solution here, which implies our $f(X)=X^4-5$ factors as

$X^4-5=(X^2-C)(X+d)(X-d)$.

So that means that your polynomial in your  field factors as 3 polynomials; one Quadratic factor and 2 linear factors, regardless of which $d$ or $b$ exist. Since you asked for the degree of each factors, this is how you would do it. If instead you asked for factorization in $\mathbb{F}_{p}$ for  $p \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$ and $p \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{5}$, that would be a different story and would require cubic reciprocity.

Comment: Thanks, but can you explain why you can just do the factorization of $x^4−5$ over $Z_{139}$  instead of  $Q_{139}$?

Comment: @Danny I'm not too sure what $\mathbb{Q}_{139}$ is. If you can tell me what that is, then I can relate it to $\mathbb{F}_{139}$. I just assumd that the factorization into irreducibles would be similair.

Comment: Thanks, $Q_{139}$ is $Q[[x]]/(x-139)$. And peter ag just answered me, that can be done actually by Gasuss' Lemma.

Comment: @Danny Oh okay! Yes, $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ for a prime $p$ in general is would give you the same kind of factorization of your irreducible as it would in $\mathbb{Q}_{p}$, assuming that $p$ doesn't divide the denominator of any element in $\mathbb{Q}_{p}$

Comment: @Danny Just to be clear: $K={\mathbb Q}_p$ is absolutely NOT ${\mathbb Q}[[ x ]] / (x-p) $ ( the latter just being the rationals). There are basically two ways of thinking of $K$ : either 1) as the quotient field of $\mathbb Z_{p}$, where the latter is the inverse limit of ${\mathbb Z}/ p^n {\mathbb Z}$, or 2) the completion of $\mathbb Q$ with respect to the $p$-adic norm $|\cdot|_p$: i.e., if $x = p^n\cdot (a/b)$, where $a$ and $b$ are prime to $p$, then $$|x|_p= {1\over p^n},$$ and of course $|0|_p = 0$. (cont)

Comment: (cont) So  two elements of $K$ are close if their difference is highly divisible by $p$. For example  if $x= 3\cdot 2^{100}$, then $|x |_2 = 1/ 2^{200}$ and is 'small' - namely $$ x \equiv 0 \pmod {2^n},$$ for all positive $n \le 200$ - i.e., up to $\delta = 1/2^{200} $, one can't tell the difference between $x$ and $0$. So, for starters, $K$ is a convenient way of talking about congruences $\pmod {p^n}$ for arbitrary (positive) $n$. The 'inverse limit' approach is to say that $\mathbb Z_p$ consists of all compatible congruences $\pmod {p^n}$ - for instance, famous example (cont) :

Comment: (cont) the infinite sum $  1 + 2 + 2^2 + \cdots + 2^n +\cdots$ converges in $\mathbb Q_2$, and the equality $$ -1 = {1\over {1 -2 } } =1 + 2 + 2^2 + \cdots + 2^n +\cdots$$ holds true ( and makes sense!). This corresponds to the following: not only $$ -1 \equiv 1 + 2  \pmod 4,$$   but also $$-1  \equiv 1 + 2 + 2^2 + \cdots + 2^n \pmod {2^{n+1}},$$ for all (positive) $n$. Now, the $-1$ on the right was an (ordinary) integer, so in $\mathbb Z_2$, we can identify that infinite sum with an integer, but "of course" there are sensible elements of $\mathbb Z_2$ which are not 'ordinary' integers...

Comment: Finally, Hensel's lemma is Newton's method from cal 1, except transported into this $p$-adic world, where it actually works better [for polys].  Say e.g. one starts with an approximation  $x_1$  for a root of a poly $f$ (i.e., $f(x_1)\equiv 0 \pmod p$). On condition $f'(x_1)\not\equiv 0 \pmod p$, the next iteration in N's method/ H's lemma gives an $x_2$ such that $x_2\equiv x_1 \pmod p$, and $$f(x_2) \equiv 0 \pmod {p^2}, $$ etc for further $x_n$.... The p-adic formulation is there exists an $x\in \mathbb Z_{p}$ such that $f(x) = 0$, and $$ x \equiv x_n \pmod {p^n},$$ for all pos. $n$.

Comment: OOOOOPPPS in my first example way above I screwed up the exponent - I meant $x= 3\cdot 2^{200}$, as I used $200$ everywhere else after - I just meant some large integer. Sigh. Sorry about that

Comment: @Danny - I don't know how comments on answers work - i.e., do you (or only Dave) see them posted, or vice versa... hence this comment - Note my OOOOPPPS comment esp.

Comment: @Davehuff - see the above sequence (note my OOOOOPPPS) comment esp.

Comment: @Davehuff -tripple OOOOOPPPPPS on my part: $\mathbb Q[[x]]/(x-p) = 0$, not the rationals! The element $x-p$ is a unit in the local ring $\mathbb Q[[x]]$, because $1/(1-t) = 1 + t + \cdots$ and a bit of algebra, so the corresponding ideal is the whole ring, and the quotient is $0$. NB All of these ooopps are a reason one shouldn't answer in comments, because when one screws up, it's hard to edit - only add to, or delete an earlier comment. Still, I hope I've helped.

Comment: @Danny - once again see above. Sigh!

Comment: @peterag Thanks, I just saw that, sorry I am sick and just come back to the website. And  thanks for your correction!